# How do I stop my laptop from waking up?

Tags: laptop, defragment, standby, task-scheduler, wake-up

I never scheduled wake up for my laptop, but after scheduling Auslogics Defragmenter to run on Sundays, 6:01AM and laptop to wake up at 6:00AM in Task Scheduler, it was waking up. Auslogics Defragmenter in my opinion was not running since after at later time when I was opening laptop's lid, I was presented dialog asking permission to run and after I allowed, Auslogics Defragmenter started, despite **"Run This Program As An Administrator"** option was checked in the **"Compatibility"** tab.

But let's assign second priority to the above problem at the moment. The main problem is that laptop **still wakes up** (after standby or hibernation) despite of me cancelling Auslogics Defragmenter schedule and **disabling** wake up in Task Scheduler.

Here is what I see in Task Scheduler:

[image]

If somebody knows a solution or has any ideas, please post your reply. Additionally if somebody has an answer or anything to suggest regarding Auslogics Defragmenter asking permission to run everytime it is scheduled to run, please reply.

**UPDATES:**

**@daxlerod**

There is something starting Auslogics Disk Defragmenter, but I do not understand how, because I disabled that task:

[image]

Here is what I just found in Task Scheduler's history:

[image]

I don't understand how it runs everyday if it is scheduled to run on Sundays, 6AM.

Comment: There is one certain way to stop it.  Remove the battery.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Disabling a task is not the same as disabling triggers associated
   with the task.
2. By default, \Microsoft\Windows\Media Center\mcupdate_scheduled is
   set to wake the computer to run the task every day.

Comment: Done! Deleted triggers and all is well. But can you tell me where triggers come from usually? I create tasks but where do i create triggers?

Answer (score 2):

Try looking in Task Scheduler again, check that you have no other active schedule. Look in Dell, Microsoft folder.

Comment: Don't see anything relevant.

Comment: Try delete the task?

Comment: Deleted triggers and everything is fine! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You might have some other scheduled task, or some other event causing your computer to wake up. The next time your computer wakes from sleep, open the command prompt and run the command `powercfg –lastwake`. The output of the command should tell you what caused your computer to wake up.

If you still cannot figure out what is causing the computer to wake, or how to fix it, add the output of the command to your question.

Edit:

Based on the output of the command, it looks like there is a different task that starts your computer. Try `SCHTASKS /Delete /TN "\Disk Defragmenter" /f` or `SCHTASKS /Delete /TN "Disk Defragmenter" /f`. I'm not sure if you need the `\` or not.

You might have more than one task that starts the computer. If your computer still starts on its own, try the `powercfg -lastwake` again to see what it is.

Comment: I have added the output.

Comment: @Boris_yo I've added more detail to my answer based on the output.

Comment: Resolved the problem!