# Why does my Dell Latitude 5580 wake every day at 06:00?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hibernate, dell-latitude, docking-station

I'm running Win10 on a Dell Latitude 5580 laptop, and I habitually hibernate it when not in use.

- If the laptop is **not** connected to the Dell dock then it reliably stays hibernated.
- If the laptop **is** connected to the Dell dock then **it wakes itself up from hibernation, every day, at exactly 06:00.**  I can then easily put it back to hibernation, and it stays that way until 06:00 the next day, or until I turn it on manually before then.

I've checked all Windows settings I can think of, and I've checked all BIOS settings, but I can't figure out why this happens. There are no scheduled tasks. There is no special Dell software installed, and I don't think that the dock itself has anything like a BIOS or other settings -- it's just a box with an USB-C cable. I have 2 monitors and a wireless Logitech keyboard attached by Unifying receiver, nothing else. There are no pets that could trample on the keyboard or push any buttons. There is no wake-on-LAN, either.

How do I turn that off?

*Edit:* I found lots more in the Task Scheduler but it looks like they are all either disabled or at least set to **not** "wake the computer to run this task." See third screenshot for example. Fuck, there are so many! If only there'd be a way to programmatically go through that entire tree! I probably shouldn't simply disable it all but so much of it looks like corpo stuff that is definitely irrelevant for a home machine.

**Task Scheduler:**
[image]

**Device Manager:**
[image]

**Nasty large tree of scheduled tasks:**
[image]

Comment: i don't know if it's a windows issues but you should include the windows version

Comment: @barlop it's literally the third word in my post ...

Comment: It’s a Dell thing. My work laptop turns on every day at 08:00 if it’s on AC power. No way to stop this. Dock or PSU directly, doesn’t matter. Colleagues laptops do it too, at different times.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun i've added it to your tags

Comment: note to self: need to try this: Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Edit Plan Settings > Change advanced power settings > Sleep > Allow wake timers. Source: https://superuser.com/a/961080/9350

Comment: note to self: also need to try the command `powercfg /LASTWAKE`. Source: https://superuser.com/q/377357/9350

Comment: Just a note because I was there when the laptop turned on today; Event Viewer reports the wake source as “unknown”. `powercfg /lastwake` has an entry but the list of wake sources is empty. // I suggest you give up. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the computer has not gone back to sleep, the command **`powercfg /LASTWAKE`** will (usually) show the reason for waking up.

This doesn't always work; sometimes there's no reason given, and sometimes the computer has gone back to sleep and then this command would report *power button* instead. But normally this helps with narrowing down the root cause.

In my case it was a backup task, which I would not have been able to find in the many hundreds of entries in the Task Scheduler *which doesn't even have a search function!*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had several computers at the office that used to wake themselves from hibernation at exact hours. Sometimes when I work on another PC in the same room, and there is no one else, I hear the machine wake. Notably, each one did it at an exact time of the day, no matter if it was workday or weekend. I was curious to find out the reason.
(1) It might be a Task Scheduler task - that has been set to execute at an exact hour. Inside "Settings => Conditions" for this exact task, it has a checkmark at "Wake the computer to execute this task". It might be difficult to find, out of many Scheduled tasks - which one has this checkmark. But it might help. (2) There is a setting of the network card that will prevent another device on the network to wake the machine sending a simple ping to it. The "Magic Packet" is defined more precisely with a port, MAC-address and IP. [image: Only-Allow-a-Magic-Packet-to-Wake]

Comment: Thank you for this idea! I checked all my networking devices and none of them are set to "allow this device to wake the computer."